# How to detect uris from moved files

Tags: java, android, path, uri

Anyone knows how to detect uris from moved files programmatically in Java/Android?When I start the app I detect all images in my phone (with their uris, path....), if I move the images with a media manager, next time I start the app I can get the whole uris again, with the new path. But, if I move these images programmatically (copying the image and deleting the image from the original path) next time I start the app the uris will be the previous path a not the new one. I'm trying to fix deleting the app cache, but doesn't work. Anyone knows what can be happen?

I tried to move the files with two functions and I have same problem:

```
public static void moveFile(ArrayList<ImagesData> images) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        File file_Source = new File(images.get(i).imagePath);
        File file_Destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PrivateGallery/" + new File(images.get(i).imagePath).getName());


        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(file_Source).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(file_Destination).getChannel();

            Log.i(TAG, "Source " + source + " destination " + destination);
            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size-count)) < size);

            //destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());

            file_Source.delete();
        }
        finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

  public void changeToNewPath(ArrayList<ImagesData> images) {

    String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PrivateGallery/";
    //TODO COMPROBAR SI EXISTE YA UN ARCHIVO CON SU NOMBRE

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {

        try { //TODO revisar lod el cambio de directorio
            //create output directory if it doesn't exist
            //File dir = new File(outputPath);
            File f = new File(images.get(i).imagePath);
            String a = f.getName();
            Log.e(TAG, a);

            in = new FileInputStream(images.get(i).imagePath);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + new File(images.get(i).imagePath).getName());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

            // write the output file
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;

            // delete the original file
            new File(images.get(i).imagePath).delete();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
            Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `ContentObserver` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html an example http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/

Comment: I think is the correct answer, but I tried to implement it and i get nothing. Because, when I move an image I have to copy that image and delete the previous one, right?. So, I think, the uri won't be the same, or it'll be? If is the same uri I just would have to change the image path. Sorry, I'm confusing, I don't know how to do this properly